# how to create multiline ion-label in ionic 5 angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am new to ionic angular and I am using ionic 5. I need to display text data in more than one line.
But when I use *ion-label* it displaying text only in one line...
when I use *ion-item* it showing some underline below the text ...

Please help me to solve

Comment: Read this: [ask], and this [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">your multiline text</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```